# Reading passive rfid in android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

Is it possible to read a passive rfid (like dogs have) with android device NFC tech?
Is there any good dev tutorial to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the type of RFID tag. Many RFID tags that operate at 13.56 MHz can communicate with Android-based NFC devices. However the RFID chips typically used to tag animals operate at around 130 kHz and use RFID standards that are not compatible to NFC.